# print out the largest number in an ArrayList

Tags: java

I want to print out the largest number in my list .. I implemented this code in java ..

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Product {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    System.out.println("Enter your number");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=0;
    while (n<3) {
    int num = scan.nextInt();
    n++;
    }
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i =0; i<list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i)>max) {
            max=list.get(i);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(max);


        }
    }
```

When I run this code I always get `-2147483648` in the output..
What did I do wrong in my code ?

Thank you

Comment: Because `list` is empty. You never add elements to it.

Comment: thank you ... but I am adding number by using Scanner as I implemented

Comment: You are never adding item to `list`.

Comment: Your variable `num` is ignored. You never add it to your list of elements. You should have `list.add(num)` in your `while` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What did you do wrong?

You take in numbers, but do not store them in the ArrayList. 
As such, your ArrayList is always empty and `min` always remains `Integer.MIN_VALUE`

You need to store them. Change your while-loop to:

```
while (n<3) {
    int num = scan.nextInt();
    list.add(num);
    n++;
}
```

Comment: Oh my God ... thank you brother :) I missed this  `list.add(num);`